# WP_Query Results Issue with ACF

Tags: wp-query

I have the following query set up

```
$argsar = array (
'numberposts'   => 1,
'post_type' => 'auctionroom',
'meta_key'  => 'auctionroom_username',
'compare' => '=',
'value'   => $auctionroomname
);
$the_queryar = new WP_Query($argsar);
if ($the_queryar->have_posts()) {
$causercheck = $the_queryar->found_posts;
$the_queryar->the_post();
$auctionroom_id = get_the_ID();
}
```

It should only return 1 result but it is returning the total number of auctionroom posts when I get

`$causercheck = $the_queryar->found_posts;`

Having numberposts or not gives the same incorrect total

Thanks in anticipation for any clues

Running
Wordpress Version: 5.5.1 with ACF Version: 5.9.1

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the format I used for `$argsar` needs to be changed to

```
$argsar = array (
        'post_type' => 'auctionroom',
        'meta_query' => array(
                  array(
                        'key'     => 'auctionroom_username',
                        'compare' => '=',
                        'value'   => $auctionroomname
                    )
                )
        );
```

Hope it helps someone